# Object.entries and addEventListener

Tags: javascript

I have this object and I want to display the key in the options that gets created and the value in the `.info <p>` tag. I then want to change the info text, when I change the city by using an addEventListener.

My question is, is it possible to use the `info` in `for(const [city, info] of entries)` in a `addEventListener function`? I tried to have the eventListener in the for loop but that didn't work out right. But can I somehow pass the info to another function? Or is it better too just loop the keys and then do another loop for the values in an addEventListener function?

```js
let citiesWithInfo = {"New York": 'The biggest city in the world.',
    "Los Angeles": 'Home of the Hollywood sign.',
    "Maui": 'A city on the beautiful island of Hawaii.',
    "Vancover": 'It\'s a city where it rains alot. And I mean alot.',
    "Miami": 'The samba city of the world.'
};

const cityWithInfoPrompt = document.querySelector('#cities-with-info');
const entries = Object.entries(citiesWithInfo);

for(const [city, info] of entries) {
    let optionCity = document.createElement("option");
    optionCity.textContent = city;
    optionCity.value = city;
    cityWithInfoPrompt.appendChild(optionCity);

    let currentCity = cityWithInfoPrompt.options[cityWithInfoPrompt.selectedIndex];
    if(currentCity.textContent == city) {
        document.querySelector(".info").textContent = info;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <select name="cities-with-info" id="cities-with-info"></select>
    <p>Info: <span class="info"></span></p>
    <script src="eventTarget.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Why not have a change listener on select and in select options you can have key as display value and description as value.Then, you just have to modify info content on selection change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the event outside the loop where you can match the value between the selected value and the object property name:

```js
let citiesWithInfo = {"New York": 'The biggest city in the world.',
    "Los Angeles": 'Home of the Hollywood sign.',
    "Maui": 'A city on the beautiful island of Hawaii.',
    "Vancover": 'It\'s a city where it rains alot. And I mean alot.',
    "Miami": 'The samba city of the world.'
};

const cityWithInfoPrompt = document.querySelector('#cities-with-info');
const entries = Object.entries(citiesWithInfo);

for(const [city, info] of entries) {
    let optionCity = document.createElement("option");
    optionCity.textContent = city;
    optionCity.value = city;
    cityWithInfoPrompt.appendChild(optionCity); 
}

cityWithInfoPrompt.addEventListener('change', function(){
  let currentCity = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  document.querySelector(".info").textContent = citiesWithInfo[currentCity];
});
// On page load
// Create event
var event = new Event('change');
// Dispatch the event
cityWithInfoPrompt.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<body>
    <select name="cities-with-info" id="cities-with-info"></select>
    <p>Info: <span class="info"></span></p>
    <script src="eventTarget.js"></script>
</body>
```

Solution using  [**Arrow Function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (`() => {}`) and [**`Event.target`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

```js
let citiesWithInfo = {"New York": 'The biggest city in the world.',
    "Los Angeles": 'Home of the Hollywood sign.',
    "Maui": 'A city on the beautiful island of Hawaii.',
    "Vancover": 'It\'s a city where it rains alot. And I mean alot.',
    "Miami": 'The samba city of the world.'
};

const cityWithInfoPrompt = document.querySelector('#cities-with-info');
const entries = Object.entries(citiesWithInfo);

for(const [city, info] of entries) {
    let optionCity = document.createElement("option");
    optionCity.textContent = city;
    optionCity.value = city;
    cityWithInfoPrompt.appendChild(optionCity); 
}

cityWithInfoPrompt.addEventListener('change', () => {
  let currentCity = event.target.value;
  document.querySelector(".info").textContent = citiesWithInfo[currentCity];
});
// On page load
// Create event
var event = new Event('change');
// Dispatch the event
cityWithInfoPrompt.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<body>
    <select name="cities-with-info" id="cities-with-info"></select>
    <p>Info: <span class="info"></span></p>
    <script src="eventTarget.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why an arrow function doesn't work in ```('change', () => {let currentCity...
});```

Comment: @hbrovell, arrow function (`() => {}`) does not have it's own `this`, thus accessing `this` will fail inside arrow function:)

Comment: @hbrovell, I have added another solution using arrow function and `event.target`, please check, thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

I used this code for the addEventListener to get the info from the object to the info HTML tag.

```
cityWithInfoPrompt.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    let selectedCity = e.target.value
    for(const [city, info] of entries) {
        if(selectedCity == city) {
            document.querySelector(".info").textContent = info;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Though the above code will give you the output, the *for* loop and the *if* condition is completely unnecessary. You can check out my answer:)